# Actions into an "if statement" are not executed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, if-statement

I need to set a text of a label if some particular conditions are true (don't pay attention to them because that part of code is correct). It should be very easy but surprisingly it does not work! That action is completely skipped. I think the problem is caused by that huge amount of "if statements".
This is my code: (the part that is skipped is in the 2nd piece of code)

```
    -(void)setCustomUsername{

        stillChecking = YES;

        ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
        ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

        [account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) 
         {
             // Did user allow us access?
             if (granted == YES)
             {
                 // Populate array with all available Twitter accounts
                 arrayOfAccounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

                 // Sanity check
                 if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0) 
                 {
                     NSString *customUser = [self updateCustomUser];
                     int numberOfAccounts = [arrayOfAccounts count];
                     int accountsAdded = 0;
                     specAccountIndex = 0;

                     NSLog(@"index 0 = %@", [[arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:0] username]);
                     NSLog(@"index 1 = %@", [[arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:1] username]);
                     NSLog(@"spec_username = %@", customUser);
                     NSLog(@"numberOfAccounts = %i", numberOfAccounts);

                     // Check if a specified username exist.
                     if (isThereASpecifiedUsername) {

                         NSLog(@"3");
                         while (numberOfAccounts > accountsAdded) {
                             NSLog(@"4");
                             if ([customUser isEqualToString:[[arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:specAccountIndex] username]]) {
                                 NSLog(@"NewTweet will use the account at index %i", specAccountIndex);
                                 accountsAdded = numberOfAccounts;
                                 stillChecking = NO;
                                 //[accountIndexLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", selAccountIndex]];
                             }
                             else{
                                 ++specAccountIndex;
                                 ++accountsAdded;
                             }
                         }
                         NSLog(@"specAccountIndex: %i", specAccountIndex);

                     }
                     else {
```

**---------------------------THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART (BELOW)----------------------------**

```
    //we set the value of a simple integer to 0
                         specAccountIndex = 0;

    //now we set the string "finalChoice" equal to specAccountIndex
                         NSString *finalChoice = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", specAccountIndex];

    //now just a check (and yes, it works)
                         NSLog(@"The app will use the account at index %@", finalChoice);

    //than we set the text of a label equal to finalChoice (This part does *NOT* work)
                         [accountIndexLabel setText:finalChoice];

    //than we check if the text has been set (This part does *NOT* work)
                         NSLog(@"accountIndexLabel check = %@", accountIndexLabel.text);

                         stillChecking = NO;
                     }

                  }}}];


        while (stillChecking) {}

        NSLog(@"accountIndexLabel check at the end of the process = %@", accountIndexLabel.text);
    }
```

Comment: Can you confirm `accountIndexLabel` is not `nil`

Comment: Volume of `if` statements is not an issue for the program itself, but it does increase the likelihood of programmer error as it becomes increasingly difficult to understand what is happening.

Comment: accountIndexLabel is 0 by default but in the nslog it appears "(null)"

Comment: Theres your problem then. You are setting `text` on a `nil` object which is a no-op. Figure out why you have `nil` and not a `UILabel` like you are expecting.

Comment: Also, can you confirm if `finalChoice` is not nil?

Comment: I'm sure that all the if-statements work well because the rest of the code is executed perfectly...

Comment: Is that `0` the expected index? I'm assuming it is as your comment in the code reads `//now just a check (and yes, it works)`

Comment: Also, if I set a value for a global variable in that if-statement, at the end of the execution of the method, the value becomes again equal to the first number! Why does this happen?

Comment: Yes, the 0 is the expected index

Comment: Your issue is that `accountIndexLabel` is `nil`. If there are other strange things happening then that is another question entirely, which is not going to get answered in comments.

Answer (score 0):

As found out in the comments by Paul, your `accountIndexLabel` is `nil`. I suppose this is because you forgot to drag a line from the UILabel to the outlet in the owner's code or forgot to add the `outlet` before your UILabel field OR if you initialize your UILabel in code that you forgot to alloc init it.

Setting a NSString onto a nil object won't raise an exception in Objective-C as it would do in other languages, in fact it's calling a setter on a `nil` object which is calling a method on a `nil` object which just does nothing in Objective-C.

Vote up Pauls comment :-)